# RPC over serial port - адекватно ли? Как делают в Enterprise?

Tags: java, serial, rpc

Насколько знаю, для разных языков программирования существует достаточно много всяких библиотечек и фреймворков, позволяющих реализовать RPC и JSON-RPC поверх HTTP/HTTPS, WebSocket, а может и простых TCP-сокетов тоже. Приходилось с подобным сталкиваться по работе на C++. В частности с **Apache Thrift**.

А как быть с COM-портами? Причем, если у тебя именно тот случай, когда для всех связываемых устройств пишешь ПО ты сам, поэтому тебе и решать, что там будет крутиться.

**Язык - Java.**

**Область - я отношу к Enterprise** - работать приходится со смарт-картами (и это не какой-нибудь СКУД, а именно те). Отчасти поэтому и язык Java, собственно.

Конечно, Java будет только на ПК, а вот связываемое устройство вряд ли ее поддерживает, да и RPC-библиотеку вряд ли потянет. Но под него можно создать "велосипед", совместимый с RPC-библиотекой, максимально упрощенный, а на ПК уж будет крутиться сама RPC-библиотека

Адекватно ли подобное?

Или для COM-порта адекватно только пилить свой протокол, разбираясь с нуля, какие таймауты ставить, как читать все байты, как оно должно реконнектиться при потере связи и т.д.?

Мне не хотелось бы пилить свой протокол, потому что у меня маловато опыта качественного программирования, а на Java и в Enterprise и с COM-портами его и вовсе нет. И если буду когда-нибудь устраиваться на работу по Java, то все эти "наработки" будут не очень-то оценены. А если у профессионалов еще и принято использовать какую-то готовую библиотеку, то на меня и вовсе будут смотреть косо. Я знаю, как это бывает на других платформах.

Comment: COM порт служит для связи с какими-то устройствами. Если ты хочешь для связи использовать "свой" протокол, значит у тебя и "свои" устройства. Если так то можно использовать модули ардуино - и  связываться с ними по websocket

Comment: @Вадим websocket можно пустить поверх COM-порта? Тогда подходит. А если нужен bluetooth/wi-fi/ethernet/..., то нет.

Comment: если постараться - то, наверно, можно, но это будет велосипед... точнее свой протокол
а чем обусловлен именно com?